# Firebaseの秘密鍵を含めてexeファイルを配布するには

Tags: python, firebase

PythonでFirebaseを実装する場合、以下のようにjsonファイルを秘密鍵として使用するかと思います。
Pythonで作ったファイルをexe化して配布しようと思った場合、jsonファイルも一緒に配布してしまうことになるかと思います。

その場合、セキュリティなどに問題は起きないのでしょうか？

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

Answer (score 0):

配布対象によりますが、基本的にサービスアカウントのJSONは限られたごく一部のサービス管理者以外が触れられないようにすべきです。

質問の方法ではサービスアカウントを利用して配布された人がサービスアカウントのフリをして操作ができてしまうので、実際にインターネット上で一般公開で配布すると緊急度の高いセキュリティインシデントになります。

クライアントに安全に認証をさせたい場合は公式SDKが対応している言語を使うか、Pythonで実施したい場合はサーバーを用意してユーザー認証を行いFirebaseのデータのやり取りを仲介させるほうがよいです